# Subtracting dates in ruby

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, time

This seems like a real straightforward thing to do but I'm having trouble with it. I have a date and I want to find out how many days are between today and that date. Here is my attempt in ruby console:

```
>> Date.today
=> Wed, 31 Jul 2013
>> date_time
=> Fri Jul 26 00:40:12 -0700 2013
>> Date.parse(date_time.to_s)
=> Wed, 26 Jul 0013
>> Date.today-Date.parse(date_time.to_s)
=> Rational(730492, 1)
```

Why am I getting this back instead of just an integer?

Comment: If your code depends on particular library, you should write that in the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like `date_time` is already a DateTime object, so why convert it to a string and reparse it?

```
require 'date'

date_time = DateTime.parse('Fri Jul 26 00:40:12 -0700 2013')
date_time.class # => DateTime
(Date.today - date_time).to_i # => 4
```

If you want to ignore the time component of the DateTime, convert it to a date:

```
require 'date'

date_time = DateTime.parse('Fri Jul 26 00:40:12 -0700 2013')
date_time.class # => DateTime
(Date.today - date_time.to_date).to_i # => 5
```

Comment: I dont think you can subtract a DateTime from a date but using to_date on the DateTime did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: You can but you'll get a rational number.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
result = Date.new(0) + ("2013-07-31".to_date - "2013-06-31".to_date)
```

and then you can use `result.year`, `result.month`, etc.

Or, you can use `to_i` like `(Date.parse('2013-07-31')-Date.parse('2013-06-31')).to_i`
because it seems you are subtracting strings rather than integers, and `to_i` solves it.

Comment: You might explain where `to_date` comes from. The OP doesn't show anything referring to Rails or other gems.

Comment: @theTinMan You can see this page, I hope it's what you mean. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Conversions/to_date